# Always start the Mac to Startup Manager without having to press and hold the Option key

Tags: macos, bootcamp, startup, dual-boot

I frequently switch between mac OS and Bootcamp.

So I was wondering if there is an option to not have a preferred Startup Disk and always start to the Startup Manager, like you would get when pressing the option key while booting.

Google couldn’t help so your support is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to install a another boot manager. The [rEFind](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) boot manager is a common choice. You will need to [download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/), [install](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html) and [configure](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html) rEFInd.

I should also point out that you can already switch to Windows from the Startup Disk pain of macOS System Preferences. Also, you should already be able to switch to macOS from the Windows system tray or from the Windows control panel.